# Using tar -cfv output Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to output the `tar -cfv` into a file; any ideas how to do this?

When i use the command `tar -cfv file.tar path`, it shows me an output, and I need to create a log file showing this output.

Comment: redirect output using `>`. Ex:-

`tar -cfv file.tar > log.txt`

Comment: `tar -cvf file.tar path > tar.contents`?  Or: `tar -cvf file.tar path | tee tar.contents`?

Comment: just `>` won't do it since the output is on `stderr`

Comment: @davejagoda: Interesting — you seem to be correct.  It's odd; it isn't error output and standard output isn't in use, so the verbose info should be going to standard output, but it doesn't.  Oh well, it shows how often I've felt it necessary to capture the output of `tar -cvf …`!

Comment: My solution was `tar -cvf file.tar path 2> logfile` but before I could submit that @ManuelBarbe's solution below was posted (which I think should be accepted as the best answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is written to standard error, not standard output.  So, either redirect the output:

```
tar -cfv file.tar path &> log_file.txt
```

Or use `tee` to show the output and log to file:

```
tar -cfv file.tar path 2>&1 | tee log_file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the first one with &>> to append

Comment: I'd recommend `|&` in place of `2>&1 |`, which is the standard shorthand.